# Como usar el valor de una variable que se lleno en un metodo, desde otro metodo

Tags: java

Tengo la siguiente clase en la cual defino la siguientes variables al inicio de la misma

```
public class generarFactura {

    String IMG = "C:\\PAM\\Facturador Electronico\\Repositorio\\FacturadorPAM\\57b29c1e5891\\web\\Resources\\img\\logo.png";
    base64 convertirBase64 = new base64();
    final String RUTA_PDF = "C:\\PAM\\Facturador Electronico\\Repositorio\\FacturadorPAM\\57b29c1e5891\\PDF";
    final String CSS = "C:\\PAM\\Facturador Electronico\\Repositorio\\FacturadorPAM\\57b29c1e5891\\web\\documentos\\style.css";
    //NOMBRE DE PRUEBA
    String nombreArchivo = "prueba.pdf";
    // Variables para agregar al PDF
    public int numeroResolInicial;
    private int numeroResolFinal;
    private String nroResolucion;
    public int tipoTransaccion;
    int idCliente;
    private String nombreCliente;
    private String direcCliente;
    private String telCliente;
    private String tipoDocCliente;
    private String docCliente;
    private String emailCliente;
    private String municipio;
    private String departamento;
    private double valDescuento;
    private double valIVA;
    private double valICA;
    private double valReteFUENTE;
    private double valReteIVA;
    private double valReteICA;
    private double valorNeto;
    private double valorBruto;
    private String subTotal;
    private String valFinalFactura;
    public String fechaExpedicion;
    public String fechaVencimiento;
    private int formaPago;
    public String observacion;
    public String factura;
    private ArrayList<String> prodValor = new ArrayList<>();
    private ArrayList<Integer> prodId = new ArrayList<>();
    private ArrayList<String> descProdValor = new ArrayList<>();
    private ArrayList<Integer> cantProdValor = new ArrayList<>();
    private ArrayList<Double> vUnitProdValor = new ArrayList<>();
    private ArrayList<Integer> descuentoProdValor = new ArrayList<>();
    private ArrayList<Integer> impIVAValor = new ArrayList<>();
    private ArrayList<Integer> impRetencionValor = new ArrayList<>();
    private ArrayList<Integer> impICAValor = new ArrayList<>();
    private ArrayList<Double> ValorTotal = new ArrayList<>();
    private ArrayList<Integer> LreteIVA = new ArrayList<>();
    private ArrayList<Integer> LreteICA = new ArrayList<>();
    private ArrayList<Double> calValFinal = new ArrayList<>();

    Image logo;

    DecimalFormat formateo = new DecimalFormat("###,###,###.##");

    public boolean generarFactura(factura tipoFactura, //tipo de formato a generar
            factura cliente, //datos del cliente
            Integer medioPago,
            String fechaExpedicion, //fecha de expedicion
            String fechaVencimiento,
            String observacion, //observaciones de la factura
            JSONArray producto, //JSONArray de productos
            JSONArray descProducto, //JSONArray descripcion Productos
            JSONArray cantProducto, //JSONArray cantidad Productos
            JSONArray vUnitario, //JSONArray valor unitario Productos
            JSONArray descuentoProd, //JSONArray descuento por Producto
            JSONArray impIVA, //JSONArray impuesto IVA por Producto
            JSONArray reteIVA,
            JSONArray impRetencion, //JSONArray impuesto retencion por Producto
            JSONArray impICA, //JSONArray impuesto ICA por producto
            JSONArray reteICA,
            JSONArray valorTotal) {                        //JSONArray valores totales por Producto

        boolean result = false;
        String sql;
        String formatoFactura = null;
        queriesSQL queries = new queriesSQL();
        conexionBD dataBase = new conexionBD();
        Connection conn;
        PreparedStatement stmt;
        ResultSet rs;

        this.fechaExpedicion = fechaExpedicion;
        this.fechaVencimiento = fechaVencimiento;
        this.formaPago = medioPago;
        this.observacion = observacion;
        //creamos una instancia para agregar el logo 
        try {
            logo = Image.getInstance(IMG, true);
        } catch (BadElementException | IOException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(generarFactura.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        //traemos el formato del tipo de documento que vamos a generar desde la BD
        try {
            Class.forName("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver");
            sql = queries.getConsulta("traerFormato");
            conn = dataBase.getConnection();
            stmt = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
            stmt.setString(1, tipoFactura.getTipoFactura());
            rs = stmt.executeQuery();

            if (rs.next()) {
                tipoFactura.setFormatoFactura(rs.getString("formato"));
                //asignamos el idTipoTransaccion a la variable global
                tipoTransaccion = rs.getInt("id_tipo_factura");
                result = true;
            }
            //decodificamos el formato en BASE64
            formatoFactura = convertirBase64.decoder(rs.getObject(3).toString());

            try {
                dataBase.closeConnection(conn, stmt, rs);
            } catch (SQLException e) {
                Logger.getLogger(generarFactura.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, e);
            }

        } catch (ClassNotFoundException | SQLException e) {
            Logger.getLogger(generarFactura.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, e);
        }
        //Llamamos al metodo que genera el documento PDF
        generarPDF(formatoFactura, cliente, fechaExpedicion, fechaVencimiento, observacion, producto, descProducto, cantProducto, vUnitario, descuentoProd, impIVA, reteIVA, impRetencion, impICA, reteICA, valorTotal);
        return result;
    }

    public boolean generarPDF(String formato, factura cliente, String fechaExpedicion, String fechaVencimiento, String observacion, JSONArray producto, JSONArray descProducto, JSONArray cantProducto, JSONArray vUnitario, JSONArray descuentoProd, JSONArray impIVA, JSONArray reteIVA, JSONArray impRetencion, JSONArray impICA, JSONArray reteICA, JSONArray valorTotal) {
        boolean generoPDF = false;
        String frtDiligenciado = null;
        StringBuilder frtoBuilder = null;
        frtoBuilder = new StringBuilder(formato);
        String sql;
        queriesSQL queries = new queriesSQL();
        conexionBD dataBase = new conexionBD();
        Connection con;
        PreparedStatement stmt;
        ResultSet rs;

        try {
            //paso 2 generacion documento
            try ( //paso 1 generacion archivo
                    OutputStream archivo = new FileOutputStream(new File(RUTA_PDF, nombreArchivo))) {
                //paso 2 generacion documento
                Document documento = new Document();
                //paso 3 generacion del archivo PDF
                PdfWriter pdf = PdfWriter.getInstance(documento, archivo);
                //paso 4 abrimos el documento
                documento.open();

                try {
                    Class.forName("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver");
                    sql = queries.getConsulta("listarCabeceraFactura");
                    con = dataBase.getConnection();
                    stmt = con.prepareStatement(sql);
                    stmt.setString(1, cliente.getNombreCliente());
                    rs = stmt.executeQuery();
                    if (rs.next()) {
                        //regimenCliente = rs.getInt("regimen");
                        this.idCliente = rs.getInt("id_cliente");
                        nombreCliente = rs.getString("nombre");
                        direcCliente = rs.getString("dirección");
                        telCliente = rs.getString("celular");
                        tipoDocCliente = rs.getString("concepto");
                        docCliente = rs.getString("documento");
                        emailCliente = rs.getString("email");
                        municipio = rs.getString("municipio");
                        departamento = rs.getString("departamento");
                    }
                    //llamamos los numeros de resolucion
                    try {
                        String sqlNroResol;
                        queriesSQL qNroResol = new queriesSQL();
                        conexionBD dbNroResol = new conexionBD();
                        Class.forName("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver");
                        sqlNroResol = qNroResol.getConsulta("numeracionFactura");
                        Connection conNroResol = dbNroResol.getConnection();
                        PreparedStatement psNroResol = conNroResol.prepareStatement(sqlNroResol);
                        ResultSet rsNroResol = psNroResol.executeQuery();

                        if (rsNroResol.next()) {
                            // asignamos los numeros de resoluciones inicial-final a las variables globlales y despues operaralas
                            numeroResolInicial = rsNroResol.getInt("numero_resol_inicial");
                            numeroResolFinal = rsNroResol.getInt("numero_resol_final");
                            // pasamos a String la resolucion para añadir al PDF
                            nroResolucion = String.valueOf(numeroResolInicial);
                        }

                        try {
                            dataBase.closeConnection(conNroResol, psNroResol, rsNroResol);
                        } catch (SQLException e) {
                            Logger.getLogger(generarFactura.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, e);
                        }

                    } catch (ClassNotFoundException | SQLException ex2) {
                        Logger.getLogger(generarFactura.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex2);
                    }

                    frtoBuilder.append("<table id='cuerpoFactura'><tr><td class='cuerpotd'>REFERENCIA</td><td class='cuerpotd' id='tdTituloDescripcion'>DESCRIPCION</td><td class='cuerpotd'>CANTIDAD</td><td class='cuerpotd'>DESCUENTO</td><td class='cuerpotd'>IVA</td><td class='cuerpotd'>V/R UNITARIO</td><td class='cuerpotd'>VALOR TOTAL</td></tr>");

                    //Convertimos todos los JSONArray a ArrayList en Java
                    try {
                        for (int i = 0; i < producto.length(); i++) {
                            prodId.add(producto.getJSONObject(i).getInt("id"));
                            prodValor.add(producto.getJSONObject(i).getString("valor"));
                        }
                        for (int i = 0; i < descProducto.length(); i++) {
                            descProdValor.add(descProducto.getJSONObject(i).getString("valor"));
                        }
                        for (int i = 0; i < cantProducto.length(); i++) {
                            cantProdValor.add(cantProducto.getJSONObject(i).getInt("valor"));
                        }
                        for (int i = 0; i < vUnitario.length(); i++) {
                            vUnitProdValor.add(vUnitario.getJSONObject(i).getDouble("valor"));
                        }
                        for (int i = 0; i < descuentoProd.length(); i++) {
                            descuentoProdValor.add(descuentoProd.getJSONObject(i).getInt("valor"));
                        }
                        for (int i = 0; i < impIVA.length(); i++) {
                            impIVAValor.add(impIVA.getJSONObject(i).getInt("valor"));
                        }
                        for (int i = 0; i < reteIVA.length(); i++) {
                            LreteIVA.add(reteIVA.getJSONObject(i).getInt("valor"));
                        }
                        for (int i = 0; i < impRetencion.length(); i++) {
                            impRetencionValor.add(impRetencion.getJSONObject(i).getInt("valor"));
                        }
                        for (int i = 0; i < impICA.length(); i++) {
                            impICAValor.add(impICA.getJSONObject(i).getInt("valor"));
                        }
                        for (int i = 0; i < reteICA.length(); i++) {
                            LreteICA.add(reteICA.getJSONObject(i).getInt("valor"));
                        }
                        for (int i = 0; i < valorTotal.length(); i++) {
                            ValorTotal.add(valorTotal.getJSONObject(i).getDouble("valor"));
                        }
                    } catch (JSONException ex) {
                        Logger.getLogger(generarFactura.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                    }
                    //Recorremos todos los ArrayList para agregarlos al Formato PDF
                    for (int i = 0; i < prodValor.size(); i++) {
                        System.out.println("prodcuto: " + prodValor.get(i));
                        frtoBuilder.append("<tr><td class='cuerpotd2'>").append(prodValor.get(i)).append("</td>");

                        for (String descProdValor1 : descProdValor) {
                            System.out.println("descripcionProducto: " + descProdValor.get(i));
                            frtoBuilder.append("<td class='cuerpotd2' id='tdDescripcion'>").append(descProdValor.get(i)).append("</td>");
                            break;
                        }
                        for (Integer cantProdValor1 : cantProdValor) {
                            System.out.println("cantidadProd: " + cantProdValor.get(i));
                            frtoBuilder.append("<td class='cuerpotd2' >").append(cantProdValor.get(i).toString()).append("</td>");
                            break;
                        }
                        for (Integer descuentoProdValor1 : descuentoProdValor) {
                            System.out.println("descuentoProd: " + descuentoProdValor.get(i));
                            frtoBuilder.append("<td class='cuerpotd2'>").append(descuentoProdValor.get(i).toString()).append(" %").append("</td>");
                            break;
                        }
                        for (Integer impIVAValor1 : impIVAValor) {
                            System.out.println("impIVAProd: " + impIVAValor.get(i));
                            frtoBuilder.append("<td class='cuerpotd2'>").append(impIVAValor.get(i).toString()).append(" %").append("</td>");
                            break;
                        }
                        for (Integer LreteIVA1 : LreteIVA) {
                            System.out.println("ReteIVAProd: " + LreteIVA.get(i));
                            break;
                        }
                        for (Integer impRetencionValor1 : impRetencionValor) {
                            System.out.println("impRetencionProd: " + impRetencionValor.get(i));
                            break;
                        }

                        for (Integer impICAValor1 : impICAValor) {
                            System.out.println("impICAProd: " + impICAValor.get(i));
                            break;
                        }

                        for (Integer LreteICA1 : LreteICA) {
                            System.out.println("ReteICAProd: " + LreteICA.get(i));
                            break;
                        }

                        for (Double vUnitProdValor1 : vUnitProdValor) {

                            //CALCULO DE LOS VALORES PARA REALIZAR LAS RESPECTIVAS OPERACIONES DE LA FACTURACION
                            double valorUnitario = vUnitProdValor.get(i);
                            valDescuento = ((descuentoProdValor.get(i) * 1.0) / 100) * vUnitProdValor.get(i);
                            valIVA = vUnitProdValor.get(i) * (impIVAValor.get(i) * 1.0 / 100);
                            valICA = vUnitProdValor.get(i) * (impICAValor.get(i) * 1.0 / 100);
                            valReteFUENTE = vUnitProdValor.get(i) * (impRetencionValor.get(i) * 1.0 / 100);
                            valReteIVA = valIVA * (LreteIVA.get(i) * 1.0 / 100);
                            valReteICA = valICA * (LreteICA.get(i) * 1.0 / 100);
                            valorBruto = vUnitProdValor.get(i) - valDescuento;
                            valorNeto = (valorBruto + valIVA) - valICA - valReteFUENTE - valReteIVA - valReteICA;
                            //añadimos el valorNeto al nuevo array para operar despues
                            calValFinal.add(valorNeto);

                            System.out.println("ValorUnitario: " + vUnitProdValor.get(i));
                            System.out.println("Descuento: " + valDescuento);
                            System.out.println("iva: " + valIVA);
                            System.out.println("ica: " + valICA);
                            System.out.println("reteFuente: " + valReteFUENTE);
                            System.out.println("calcreteIVA: " + valReteIVA);
                            System.out.println("calcreteICA: " + valReteICA);
                            System.out.println("valor total: " + valorNeto);

                            frtoBuilder.append("<td class='cuerpotd2'>").append("$ ").append(formateo.format(valorUnitario)).append("</td>");

                            break;
                        }

                        for (Double ValorTotal1 : ValorTotal) {
                            double valorTotal1 = ValorTotal.get(i);
                            System.out.println("valorTotalProd: " + ValorTotal.get(i));
                            frtoBuilder.append("<td class='cuerpotd2'>").append("$ ").append(formateo.format(valorTotal1)).append("</td>");
                            break;
                        }
                        frtoBuilder.append("</tr>");
                    }

                    //calculamos el subtotal de los productos
                    double subTotalProd = 0;
                    for (Double ValorTotal1 : ValorTotal) {
                        subTotalProd += ValorTotal1;
                        System.out.println("subTotal: " + subTotalProd);
                        subTotal = String.valueOf(formateo.format(subTotalProd));
                    }

                    //Despues de operados los valores, sumamos todos los valores para calcular el valor final de la Factura
                    double calcValFinal = 0;
                    for (int i = 0; i < calValFinal.size(); i++) {
                        calcValFinal += calValFinal.get(i);
                        System.out.println("valor final: " + calcValFinal);
                        valFinalFactura = String.valueOf(formateo.format(calcValFinal));
                    }

                    frtoBuilder.append("</table><table id='pieFactura'><tr><td id='tdObservacion'>Observaciones : <br/> TAG_OBSERVACIONES</td><td><table id='valores'><tr><td class='pietd'>SUBTOTAL</td><td>TAG_SUBTOTAL</td></tr><tr><td class='pietd'>TOTAL</td><td class='pietd'>TAG_MONEDA</td><td>TAG_VALOR_FINAL</td></tr></table></td></tr></table>");

                    frtDiligenciado = frtoBuilder.toString();
                    System.out.println(fechaVencimiento);
                    //llamamos los datos de la BD y reemplazamos por los TAGS del archivo
                    String p = String.valueOf(tipoTransaccion);
                    frtDiligenciado = frtDiligenciado.replace("TAG_NOMBRE_CLIENTE", nombreCliente)
                            .replace("TAG_DIR_CLIENTE", direcCliente)
                            .replace("TAG_TEL_CLIENTE", telCliente)
                            .replace("TAG_TDOC_CLIENTE", tipoDocCliente)
                            .replace("TAG_DOC_CLIENTE", docCliente)
                            .replace("TAG_EMAIL_CLIENTE", emailCliente)
                            .replace("TAG_CIUDAD_CLIENTE", municipio)
                            .replace("TAG_DEPART_CLIENTE", departamento)
                            .replace("TAG_FECHA_EXPEDICION", fechaExpedicion)
                            .replace("TAG_OBSERVACIONES", observacion)
                            .replace("TAG_NUM_RESOLUCION", nroResolucion)
                            .replace("TAG_LOGO", p)
                            .replace("TAG_FECHA_VENCIMIENTO", fechaVencimiento)
                            .replace("TAG_SUBTOTAL", "$ " + subTotal)
                            .replace("TAG_VALOR_FINAL", "$ " + valFinalFactura);

                    factura = convertirBase64.encoderFormato(frtDiligenciado);

                } catch (ClassNotFoundException | SQLException ex) {
                    Logger.getLogger(generarFactura.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                }

                //seteamos el tamaño y la alineacion del logo y lo agregamos al documento
                logo.setAlignment(Element.ALIGN_TOP);
                logo.setAbsolutePosition(28f, 765f);
                logo.scaleAbsolute(140f, 35f);
                documento.add(logo);

                //implementacion CSS
                InputStream fileCSS = new FileInputStream(CSS);
                //implementacion HTML
                InputStream origen = new ByteArrayInputStream(frtDiligenciado.getBytes());
                // parsear HTML a PDF
                XMLWorkerHelper.getInstance().parseXHtml(pdf, documento, origen, fileCSS);
                // cerrar documento y archivo
                documento.close();
            }

            generoPDF = true;

        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            Logger.getLogger(generarFactura.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, e);
        } catch (DocumentException | IOException e) {
            Logger.getLogger(generarFactura.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, e);
        }
        return generoPDF;
    }

    public boolean guardarCabeceraFactura() {
        boolean result = false;
        System.out.println(this.fechaExpedicion);
        System.out.println(fechaExpedicion);
        System.out.println(fechaVencimiento);
        System.out.println(numeroResolInicial);
        System.out.println("idcliente: "+idCliente);
        System.out.println(tipoTransaccion);
        System.out.println(factura);
        return result;
    }

    public boolean guardarDetalleFactura() {
        boolean result = false;
        return result;
    }
}
```

todas estas variables las lleno en los metodos generarFactura() y generarPDF(), sin embargo quiero utilizarlas en el metodo guardarCabeceraFactura() sin embargo ya no traen el valor, alguien me puede decir que error estoy cometiendo.

De antemano gracias a todos.

Aqui esta la instancia

===========================

```
factura f = new factura();
generarFactura gf = new generarFactura();
int boton = jObj.getInt("boton");
if (boton == 1) {
    System.out.println("entro al boton 1");
    f.setTipoFactura(jObj.getString("tipoFactura"));
    f.setNombreCliente(jObj.getString("cliente"));
    Integer medioPago = jObj.getInt("metodo_pago");
    // f.setMoneda(jObj.getInt("moneda"));
    String fechaVenc = jObj.getString("fechaVencimiento");
    String fechaExp = jObj.getString("fechaExpedicion");
    String observacion = jObj.getString("observacion");
    JSONArray producto = jObj.getJSONArray("producto");
    JSONArray descProducto = jObj.getJSONArray("descripcion");
    JSONArray cantProducto = jObj.getJSONArray("cantidad");
    JSONArray vUnitario = jObj.getJSONArray("valorUnitario");
    JSONArray descuentoProd = jObj.getJSONArray("descuento");
    JSONArray impIVA = jObj.getJSONArray("impIVA");
    JSONArray impRetencion = jObj.getJSONArray("impuestoRetencion");
    JSONArray impICA = jObj.getJSONArray("impICA");
    JSONArray valorTotal = jObj.getJSONArray("valorTotal");
    JSONArray reteIVA = jObj.getJSONArray("reteIVA");
    JSONArray reteICA = jObj.getJSONArray("reteICA");

    boolean gfPDF = gf.generarFactura(f, f, medioPago, fechaExp,
            fechaVenc, observacion, producto, descProducto,
            cantProducto, vUnitario, descuentoProd, impIVA, reteIVA,
            impRetencion, impICA, reteICA, valorTotal);
    if (gfPDF) {
        respuesta = "{result: " + "ok}";
    } else {
        respuesta = "{result: " + "ERROR}";
    }
} else if (boton == 2) {
    System.out.println("entro al boton 2");
    boolean gfGuardaFactura = gf.guardarCabeceraFactura();
    if (gfGuardaFactura) {
        respuesta = "{result: " + "ok}";
    } else {
        respuesta = "{result: " + "ERROR}";
    }
}

System.out.println(respuesta);
JSONObject jsonGFPDF = new JSONObject(respuesta);
response.setContentType("application/json");
response.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
response.getWriter().write(jsonGFPDF.toString());
```

Comment: Todas esas variables deberian existir en todos los metodos que decis, siempre y cuando estes usando la misma instancia del objeto que creaste. Podrias mostrar como haces las llamadas?

Comment: Primero que todo gracias!, ya agregue lo que me pediste

Answer (score 0):

Tu problema es totalmente de logica.

tu metodo crea una nueva factura cada vez que entra:

Al hacer

```
generarFactura gf = new generarFactura();
```

Estas creando una nueva instancia de un objeto, distinto al que usaste antes. Es mas, el que creaste al apretar el boton uno, desaparecio una vez que terminaste de usarlo.

Si quisieras usar siempre la misma factura, deberias definirla a un nivel mas alto y crearla solamente cuando apretas crear factura, y en los otros metodos controlar que exista.

### Notas al margen

- Porque tu metodo GenerarFactura recibe 2 veces el mismo parametro f?
- porque haces esto? `respuesta = "{result: " + "ok}";` que es lo mismo que esto?    `respuesta = "{result: ok}";`

Comment: Gracias por la observacion, hice caso y declare la instancia del objeto en un nivel superior.

Frente a las observaciones , el metodo generarFactura recibe dos veces el parametro F, por que hace referencia a una clase

y Por lo otro solo fue forma de como se ha manejado la respuesta,

Gracias por tu ayuda

Comment: @PabloAndresGutierrezGuerrer por favor lee el [tour]. Es importante que sepas como funciona el sitio para que recibas siempre mejores respuestas.No tiene ningun sentido que mandes dos veces f.